# A property of $f^*$ (Hardy-Littlewood maximal function) when $f$ is integral and not identically 0

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

This is the second part of Problem 3.5.4 from Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis text. I'm not sure how to start this problem.

The Hard-Littlewood maximal function is defined as follows: if $f$ is integrable on $\Bbb R^d$, we define its **maximal function** $f^*$ by

$$
f^*(x) = sup_{x \in B} \frac{1}{m(B)} \int_B |f(y)|dy, ~~x \in \Bbb R^d
$$

## Problem 3.5.4

Let $f$ be integrable on $\Bbb R^d$ and not identically zero. Show that the weak type estimate
$$
m(\{ x : f^*(x) > \alpha\}) \le c/\alpha
$$

for some $c > 0$ and all $\alpha > 0 $ whenever $\int|f| = 1$ is best in the following sense: if $f$ is supported in the unit ball with $\int |f| = 1$, then

$$
m(\{ x : f^*(x) > \alpha\}) \ge c'/\alpha
$$

for some $c' > 0$ and sufficiently small $\alpha$.

Comment: is. $f^*$ the radially decreasing rearrangement of $f$?

Comment: It's the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function. I just included the definition in the post.

Comment: Ah, apologies!!